# NG FILE UPLOAD and Sails JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js, ng-file-upload

I'm uploading an image(s) for a certain item. I see the files are being stored and saved in the server just fine but yet it gives me a 404 error when the UI's supposed to show it, if I refresh in 2 seconds, it appears correctly.

I know this is weird and that I didn't give much information or code, it would be a mess if I paste all the functions and backend calls I'm doing, I just want to know if someone's has dealed with this kind of things or knows what it can be.

I

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was that I was uploading the file(s) to the assets folder, and the view can't access to the files there, it searches for the ones in .tmp, so I uploaded them to .tmp and then copied them to assets, so in the next app lift, these files are copied to .tmp again, cause tmp is destroyed as soon as the server is stopped.